# Data is not available after switching db folder in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have switched the data folder location in `/etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties` to `org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db.test`. I started the Neo4j server successfully. Unfortunately the graph data is unavailable.

Comment: You should add more detail. E.g. your folder layout or logfiles (data/log) and (data/graph.db.test/messages.log). Can you also check in the top-left tab of the Neo4j Browser which location it uses.

Comment: neo4j.0.0.log :
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Jun 16, 2014 10:27:51 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Jun 16, 2014 10:27:51 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'

Comment: messages.log :
[o.n.k.i.n.x.NeoStoreXaDataSource]: NeoStore closed
2014-06-16 11:57:57.123+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- STOPPING diagnostics START ---
2014-06-16 11:57:57.123+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- STOPPING diagnostics END ---
2014-06-16 11:57:57.124+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.d.LifecycleManagingDatabase]: Successfully stopped database
2014-06-16 11:57:57.124+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer]: Successfully shutdown database.